# Fermi Level of an alloy

Tags: crystal-structure, electronic-configuration, materials, metallurgy

How could one calculate the Fermi level of a copper-nickel alloy? They are both structurally face-centered cubic, however how would this structure affect the Fermi level of the individual atom or the entirety of the material?

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean when you say the Fermi level of an individual atom. Since the Fermi level is defined in a statistical sense, it applies to the entirety of the solid.  And, while Cu and Ni are both fcc metals, the binary phase diagram exhibits a miscibility gap up to about 400C. above that they are mutually soluble across the entire composition range.  What information do you want to get to using the Fermi level? That might perhaps be an easier question to answer.